# "As many as 100.000 nurses" vs "Around/about/almost/nearly 100.000 nurses"? Are they the same?

Tags: meaning, adjectives, idiomatic-language, comparative-constructions, idioms-in-context

This is from [a CNN article](https://www.cnn.com/2022/12/12/business/uk-strikes-nurses/index.html):

> **As many as 100,000 members** of the Royal College of Nursing will walk out across England, Wales and Northern Ireland on Thursday.

When I read the sentence, **"as many as"** seems to have the same meaning as **"almost/nearly/around/about 100.000 nurses".** But I am not quite sure; maybe we should only use it if the number after **"as many as"** is a very high number such as this 100000. Is that really so?

Would it sound unnatural if one said **"I lost as many as 3 kg?"**

Comment: They mean **the same thing**.  "About"  You'd say ".. as much as three kg".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my opinion *as many as* in this case is referring to uncertainty.

It's like *my car can drive as many as 10km on a single litre of fuel*. This would likely mean, under perfect environmental and road conditions, driving a steady slow speed in a straight line, you can drive for 10km. But if these conditions are not met, then you will not reach that amount.

In the example, that number is probably the upper limit of a very uncertain estimate (plus a little bit for dramatic effect).

*almost* and *nearly* would mean you were pretty close but just under the number, probably around 90k-100k.

*around* and *about* would mean that number plus or minus a small amount, probably around 95k-105k.

All in all, the phrase basically means nothing. Yes there could be 100k nurses leaving, but it could just be a thousand or so. Any of the alternative words you suggested are far more specific, and would imply a greater sense of certainty. Reading that phrase (and knowing a little of the CNN) I would guess that they would probably think between 0 and 70k nurses would leave.

---

Though the phrasing is slightly weird and you would probably need context, your example of losing as many as 3kg still wouldn't make too much sense because there isn't really any uncertainty, as you would most likely know about how much weight you lost. So 'around' would make more sense. Something like "I plan on losing as many as 3kg (of fat)" would still be kind of awkward phrasing ("up to" would be better here), but would make sense at least. As it conveys you are trying to lose weight and have a limit on how much you can/want to lose.

Perhaps it would make sense in the positive direction (lost at least 3kg) and more-so if the person saying that would be referring to someone else, as there is uncertainty in that case; "wow, you look like you've lost at least 3kg"

Comment: "only use it if [we want] the number after "as many as" [to be] very high [so that we get the highest knee-jerk we can get in a headline]." *All in all, the phrase basically means nothing.* +1. Anywhere from zero to one hundred thousand.

Comment: The number seems like it's coming from [RCN's own press release](https://www.rcn.org.uk/news-and-events/news/uk-december-strike-locations-confirmed-291122) — I presume the uncertainty is that, until the actual day of the strikes, they don't know how many of their members will take part. Their membership is >430K so I presume the "as many as"/"up to" are referring to the fact that 100K is the upper bound of people represented by the RCN currently in a dispute with the government (e.g. some subset of the 430K who work in England, for the NHS etc)

Comment: The idiom "as many as" is DEFINITELY approximate. So YES it can be "even a little higher than that".

Comment: As Boba Fit says, ‘as many as’ also emphasises the magnitude of the number, with a slight implication that you might not otherwise expect it to be so large.

Comment: Aequitas, regarding the "3kg".  It would be common to utter that in a context like: "Hmm, control group A lost as many as 8, even 9 kg in the first week ..."  And also a detail, I believe you could say "many" rather than "much" if it's a larger counting-ish number (say, 9, 10, 20), but (OP) in general it would be "much" for a non-counting substance.

Comment: @Fattie I think your example is a bit different, because there's no uncertainty, it is saying that one person lost 8kg, one person lost 9kg and the other people lost less than 8kg (known, but unspecified amounts).

Answer (score 10):

Literally, "*as many as 100,000 nurses*" means "***up to** 100,000 nurses*", not "almost/nearly/around/about".

In a news story, "*as many as*" is typically *weasel words* that actually mean something like "*the highest number among the various estimates we have*". In other words, the true number is probably lower than 100,000, but that's the most impressive number they can justify using.

"As many as" also sometimes carries the nuance of surprise or astonishment at the size of a number. So if CNN is using it, it means they want the viewers to understand that this is a significantly large number.

So about your weight loss joke. Since "weight" is *uncountable*, the joke would be phrased, "*I lost **as much as** 3 kg!*" And yes, it would be funny, partly because 3 kg is not an astonishingly high number, but mostly because "as many as" means 3 kg is the *highest possible estimate*, which implies that the true number is probably a lot lower, so it sounds like you're trying to make losing a mere 1 kg sound significant. And that's hilarious!

Comment: Does 'as many as' imply 'no less than', that is, possibly more than?

Comment: @Michael No, it means there is line in the sand at that number and no number beyond it is part of it.

Comment: @Michael
 No. "As many as" indicates the *maximum possible value*.

Comment: Exactly--"as many as" is frequently used to exaggerate. We expect a dozen people to be affected by action X, but if we admit that, nobody will care. So instead we check some stats, and find that "as many as" two hundred thousand *could* theoretically be affected, so that's what ends up in the news.

Comment: Except the article doesn't say "as many as 100.000 nurses *could* walk out", but "as many as 100.000 nurses *will* walk out". So if they actually expect the number to be lower than 100.000, they're outright lying. It's true that "as many as" is often employed by people who are exaggerating or outright lying, but the literal meaning of "as many as 100.000" *is not* "at most 100.000". Also, losing 3kg in a short period can be pretty impressive.

Comment: "as many as" does not indicate a maximum possible value. It indicates a likely high estimate, a probable maximum, but not an absolute or certain maximum. It's normally used in predictions about the future in conditions of uncertainty, when it means "possibly this many, probably less, but we don't know". If they said "As many as 1000 could turn out" but actually 1001 turned out, that would not be a contradiction.

Comment: Literally means **nothing** in English. Almost everything is idomatic.

Comment: @Fattie Yes, but not *literally* nothing.

Comment: (1) My comment (just above) meant: "In English, the 'dictionary' meaning of a phrase, means nothing." In fact, I do mean, it has 0.0000 weight. The "dictionary meaning" of a phrase, has "truly" (*we'll come back to this issue*) 0.0000 value to determining the actual meaning of the speaker. English is nowadays *that* idiomatic, sarcastic, implied.  Interestingly gotube, a recently "de-literalized" word is ... wait for it ... "literal" or "literally".  The actual meant meaning of "literal" in at least 999/1000 uses, is "somewhat".  ("She literally had kittens.") Indeed, same with "truly".

Comment: When I say "999/1000" I did so because I can't find another term anymore (!)  So, in the past, call it a decade, probably two, I have not once heard a casual speaker use "literally" in the "old" meaning, ie as you and i would use it. In casual writing, ditto.  In careful speaking or writing (say, TV newscasts), I'd say it's down to 10%-20% of the time used in the "old" meaning.  "Literally" now - very simply - means "very". The change will be noted in dictionaries in a few years. This is the constant, normal, course of English for, as far as I know, certainly a century.

Comment: MO, tube !!!  :)

Comment: @Fattie And yet, you knew that I meant literally literally. Context is king.

Comment: quite right !!!

Answer (score 2):

All of these have overlapping meaning and are very similar. They have slightly different meanings.

- "As many as" means the number with emphasis or surprise at how big the number is. "We had 10 guests for dinner last night." "As many as that?" expressing surprise.
- Almost and nearly suggest that it is quite close but not quite the quoted number.
- Around and about suggest it could be slightly bigger or smaller.

For the last example it should be "I lost as much as 3 kg" since weight loss is not a digital thing. You don't want a counting word but a quantity word. And here it is similar to the "as many as" in that it expresses emphasis or surprise.

Comment: Does 'as many as' imply 'no less than', that is, possibly more than?

Comment: @Michael, no, I think of "as many as" as meaning "less than or equal to." Think of the phrase in the context of "_could be_ as many as," and it makes a little more sense. This in contrast to "as few as," which would mean "greater than or equal to."

Comment: @Michael it is APPROXIMATE.  So it could be A BIT MORE than the number given.